# What is the Token Standard used by the balances pallet to issue the native token for the chain in the substrate kitchen sink node?

Tags: balances, token

We are using the kitchen sink substrate node with the standard balances pallet. No changes. The chain mints native tokens using the usual processes. My question is: **what token standard is used in the standard Substrate balances pallet**? ERC-20, or BEP or EVM Compatible? Or something else? I have not seen this discussed.

Comment: I believe that token standards are specific to smart contracts and therefore DOT and other Substrate based tokens from the balances pallet do not use a token standard. Can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any external 'token standard' is applicable here. If you would like to know what kind of operations are supported you can look at the traits implemented by `balances` pallet: [Currency](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/currency/trait.Currency.html), [LockableCurrency](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/currency/trait.LockableCurrency.html), [ReservableCurrency](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/currency/trait.ReservableCurrency.html).

Comment: Thank you, Adam!